# is it possible to increase disk size by using/adding another clean disk

Tags: linux, lvm, hard-disk, disk, volume

we have the following disks from `lsblk` , all disks are not lvm

```
sdc                8:32   0    80G  0 disk /var/hadoop1
sdd                8:48   0    80G  0 disk /var/hadoop2
sde                8:64   0    80G  0 disk
sdf                8:80   0    80G  0 disk
```

`sdc` and `sdd` disks are full ( 100% used )

the status is that `sdc` and `sdd` disks are full and we can use them

but we have  a new disks sde and sdf , each disk with size of `20G`

so

is it possible to add the `sde` disk to `sdc` in order to give another 20G for sdc ?

Comment: I think the disks are vmdk disk ( appears in vmware vcenter )

Comment: we cant - we not get approval for grow the disks  , so we are stuck , but maybe we can used the other disks ? but how?

Comment: yes , I know this is silly , but we cant for now , and cluster is with downtime

Comment: lets say we get approval and they grow the disks to 120G then what are the steps from my side ( we have redhat 7.x )

Comment: @StephenKitt, we get approval now they increase ( grow to 200G ) , please can you give the commands that we need to do on the OS , so OS disks will grow also

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222860/86440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding disks on the level of operation system you can do this directly in hadoop. You can add them to the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` property. The format is

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///disk/c0t2,/disk/c0t3,/dev/sde,/dev/sdf</value>
</property>
```

I am not 100% sure hadoop can handle RAW disks. In such case you can create on each new disk one big partition, format it, mount it `/var/hadoop3`, `/var/hadoop4` and use format:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///disk/c0t2,/disk/c0t3,/var/hadoop3,/var/hadoop4</value>
</property>
```